Sales Cloud as Activation Target for Data Cloud
Can Sales Cloud be an Activation Target in Data Cloud? How can we expose attributes from data cloud on the Contact page in Sales Cloud ? (in the form of related lists or something)
I need to construct a visual Customer 360 view of a Customer in Sales Cloud (using data from Data Cloud)
How can I do that?

Yes it can be a target, by publishing Platform Events and then consuming those to update records within Sales Cloud. In terms of a related list, you can either use the Dynamic Related List component (assuming you have a relationship to that Contact) or you could create an LWC that retrieves the data from Data Cloud via the native APIs. What have you tried to date? What isn't working? You should [edit] your question to provide more detail because you're unlikely to get much more of an answer without doing so.

There's no activation targets that go to CRM. The data is available in many other ways:

Related Lists & Dynamic Related Lists
Copy Field Enrichment (will run on all records, can get expensive)
Query API in a custom lightning web component
Data Actions & Platform Events (can be overkill depending on what you need)

It generally makes sense to rely on queries rather than activation since you'll retrieve the freshest data whenever needed, you'll be designing credit conscious solutions, and respects Data Cloud's role as a system of reference.
